# Lifetime management of lists and documents in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Can I do the following with SharePoint 2007:

1) Create lists (records) and document libraries with content that is in force for a certain amount of days and after that, they automatically expire? How?

2) When searching for words in a SharePoint site where there are lists and documents, SharePoint displays results similar to Google, would it be possible that Sharepoint tell me what documents are no longer current? How?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would recommend changing the title of the question

Comment: Yeah, Occitan not being widely-spoken on SO.

Comment: Riffnl, I feel that the correction made by Miky is good for me. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you might want to check out Information Management Policies

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101735291033.aspx

HTH